# Self Implementing Dictionary, but with custom class as key

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, inheritance, interface

I have an exercise that I am doing to help me understand and learn about the use of generics, and the understanding of interfaces and interface inheritance. This is done by implementing and using my own class(es).

I think I have done part `1` successfully (followed a tutorial) and was able to hash and add to my dictionary without any problems. If there are parts I am missing from the solution to part `1` feel free to let me know.

The second part is the main problem. From what I understood I am supposed to let the key be the  `latitude` and `longitude` of a city. My own implementation of Dictionary `Dict` is of the `Dict<K, V>` so it is not possible to have the key be of 2 values.

That is where I think `struct` could come in and pass my `struct` as the key while storing the values for `latitude` and `longitude`.

Below I will try to outline the exercise description with the requirements to make my question more understandable.

---

*The exercise has 2 parts*

**Part 1**

> In this part you will create your own class that implements the IDictionary<K,V>.
>
> In order to implement the IDictionary<K,V> you must implement the ICollection, and the IEnumerable interfaces.
>
> You are not allowed to use the `C#` Dictionary implementation as a delegate as this would make the exercise insignificant.

**Part 2**

> We want to use the recently created Dictionary class to map the latitude and longitude values to their matching cities.
>
> The key itself should be a class that represents a `GeoLocation` consisting of a `latitude` and a `longitude`. Make all the necessary functions and operator overloads to make it possible to use this class as a key for the Dictionary  class

---

### Code

**Dict** :

```
 public class Dict<K, V>:IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>>
    {
        private const int INI_Size = 16;
        LinkedList<KeyValuePair<K, V>>[] values;

        public Dict()
        { 
            this.values = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<K, V>>[INI_Size];
        }

        public int Count { get; private set; }
        public int Capacity
        {
            get
            {
                return this.values.Length;
            }
        }

        public void Add(K key, V value)
        {
            var hash = this.HashKey(key);

            if(this.values[hash]== null)
            {
                this.values[hash] = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<K, V>>();
            }

            var keyExistsAlready = this.values[hash].Any(p => p.Key.Equals(key));

            if (keyExistsAlready)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("key already exist");
            }

            var pair = new KeyValuePair<K, V>(key, value);
            this.values[hash].AddLast(pair);
            this.Count++;

            if (this.Count >= this.Capacity * 0.75)
            {
                this.ResizeAndReAddValues();
            }
        }

        public V Find (K key)
        {
            var hash = this.HashKey(key);
            if(this.values[hash] == null)
            {
                return default(V);
            }
            var collection = this.values[hash];
            return collection.First(p => p.Key.Equals(key)).Value;
        }

        public bool ContainsKey(K key)
        {
            var hash = HashKey(key);

            if (this.values[hash] == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var collection = this.values[hash];
            return collection.Any(pair => pair.Key.Equals(key));
        }

        private int HashKey(K key)
        {
            var hash = Math.Abs(key.GetHashCode()) % this.Capacity;
            return hash;
        }

        private void ResizeAndReAddValues()
        {
            var cachedValues = this.values;
            this.values = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<K, V>>[2 * this.Capacity];
            this.Count = 0;
            foreach (var collection in cachedValues)
            {
                if (collection != null)
                {
                    foreach (var value in collection)
                    {
                        this.Add(value.Key, value.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<K, V>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach(var collection in this.values)
            {
                if (collection != null)
                {
                    foreach (var value in collection)
                    {
                        yield return value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

**GeoLocation** :

```
 public struct GeoLocation
    {
        public float X;
        public float Y;

        public GeoLocation(float x, float y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }
```

---

### My thought process

if I used the already implemented `Dictionary` from `System.Collections.Generic`

```
var dict = new Dictionary<GeoLocation, string>() {
    [new GeoLocation(12, 78)] = "Paris",
    [new GeoLocation(98, -18)] = "Frankfurt"
};
        //test for part 1 (works)
       /* var d = new Dict<int, string>
        {
            { 10, "Washington" }
        };*/
```

This is possible, would I do the same with my implementation or is the solution completely different to what I imagine?

Another thing to add as I have said from before if my implementation is also wrong on part `1` please let me know as I am trying to understand thing by coding and asking questions.

Comment: Part 1 asks you to implement `IDictionary` (which implies `ICollection`), and you did not do that at all.

Comment: _"so it is not possible to have the key be of 2 values"_ - yes you can - use a _tuple_.

Comment: "so it is not possible to have the key be of 2 values." The possibility of this aside, the exercise does not require you to have 2 values as the key. It asks you to use a *class*, not a struct, as the key. Please read the instructions carefully.

Comment: @Sweeper so what I need to do 1. Implement `ICollection`and 2. My thought process was wrong and `GeoLocation` needs to be a class and not a `struct`. Thanks for the feedback the question might seem dumb for some, but I am kinda new to C# so trying to learn

Comment: My hint is to implement a custom hash function.  But this can have grave consequences, later on. Your instinct of struct it spot on, never hash a mutable object for storage. I will leave it as an exercise, to find the error, but is has to do with the reference count and garbage collection and the disparity of the hash.

Comment: You are calling `key.GetHashCode()` && `Key.Equals(key)`. So long as your struct implements these methods correctly, it should work as a dictionary key.

Comment: your capacity property is misleading. Its a count of the buckets, which is an internal implementation detail and so should not be public

Comment: I do not recommend `Math.Abs` for hashes because `Abs` will throw `OverflowException` if the hash is `int.MinValue` (which is a possible value for a hash). Implementing your own `Abs` does not automatically work either, since negating `int.MinValue` would just give you `int.MinValue` back again. You can use `hash & int.MaxValue` to guarantee that the result is non-negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not going to give you a plug and play answer, as this is an exercise, and I find it problematic to just solve it for you.

I'll give you some hints that should be sufficient, and some feedback to your code.

---

First of all:

Implement IDictionary<TK, TV> to get the syntax mentioned in your post for free (and a standardized API that everyone knows how to use in C#).

---

Some general tips:

- Hide implementation details (also mentioned by pm100)
- Unit-Test implementation, specifically also for edge cases (always write tests please!)
- Use modern C#:

```cs
private int HashKey(TKey key)
{
    var hash = Math.Abs(key.GetHashCode()) % this.Capacity;
    return hash;
}
```

could be

```
private int HashKey(TKey key)
    => Math.Abs(key.GetHashCode()) % this.Capacity;
```

and

```
public bool IsReadOnly 
{
    get { return false; }
}
```

could be

```
public bool IsReadOnly => false;

// or

public bool IsReadOnly { get; } = false;
```

---

Some more specific tips:

A key used in a dictionary (This is a simplification but these are usually the most two relevant) behaves according to two properties:

- Equality: The dictionary uses comparison (e.g. the equals method or the == operator) to decide if two elements (of type key) are equal
- Hashing: The key must implement a hash function that holds to the following:

  - When Equals returns true, the `GetHashCode` function must return the same hash code for those objects deemed "equal"
  - `GetHashCode` may return the same value for many unequal objects. This is fine - it may hurt performance if there are many collisions, but it must not be unique for a group of equal objects. Microsoft says the following:

> Do not test for equality of hash codes to determine whether two objects are equal.

So after you found your candidate(s) through the hash code, you **must** check for equality. You already do that correctly in your find method.

---

So: Implement Hashing and Equality correctly for your Key. The default in C# is (for your own classes) reference equality. Override the equality and hashing functions for your type that you use as key.

Structs are fun, as they are compared by-value as a default, and GetHashCode behaves in a way that is useful for you. The modern way would be to use records (or record structs) to get equality and hash code for free. I would recommend you understand both concepts enough to implement them manually to avoid possible mis-understandings and bugs in the future!

Answer (score 3):

### As

it seems like my solution is not completely done for part `1` I will post where I am at with the implementation of the Dictionary. I am doing this so the question doesn't get confusing for others and it will also showcase my progress.

---

**Dict** :

```
public class Dict<TKey, TValue> : ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    private const int INI_Size = 16;
    LinkedList<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>[] values;

    public Dict()
    {
        this.values = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>[INI_Size];
    }

    public int Count { get; private set; }
    public int Capacity
    {
        get
        {
            return this.values.Length;
        }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly 
    {
        get { return false; }
    }


    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        var hash = this.HashKey(item.Key);
        if (this.values[hash] == null)
        {
            this.values[hash] = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>();
        }

        var keyExistsAlready = this.values[hash].Any(p => p.Key.Equals(item.Key));

        if (keyExistsAlready)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("key already exist");
        }

        var pair = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(item.Key, item.Value);
        this.values[hash].AddLast(pair);
        this.Count++;

        if (this.Count >= this.Capacity * 0.75)
        {
            this.ResizeAndReAddValues();
        }

    }


    public TValue Find(TKey key)
    {
        var hash = this.HashKey(key);
        if (this.values[hash] == null)
        {
            return default(TValue);
        }
        var collection = this.values[hash];
        return collection.First(p => p.Key.Equals(key)).Value;
    }


    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        var hash = HashKey(item.Key);

        if (this.values[hash] == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var collection = this.values[hash];
        return collection.Any(pair => pair.Key.Equals(item.Key));
    }


    private int HashKey(TKey key)
    {
        var hash = Math.Abs(key.GetHashCode()) % this.Capacity;
        return hash;
    }

    private void ResizeAndReAddValues()
    {
        var cachedValues = this.values;
        this.values = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>[2 * this.Capacity];
        this.Count = 0;
        foreach (var collection in cachedValues)
        {
            if (collection != null)
            {
                foreach (var value in collection)
                {
                    this.Add(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var collection in this.values)
        {
            if (collection != null)
            {
                foreach (var value in collection)
                {
                    yield return value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
 }
```

As part `2` is connected to part `1` it is the safest to wait for feedback on this solution. Before continuing with the exercise.

Hopefully I am not confusing anyone.

Comment: You're still not implementing the `IDictionary<K, V>` interface.